# import issues with maintaining 2 different python folders

Tags: python, directory

```
dirFoo1\
    Foo1.py
    lib\
       bar1.py
dirFoo3
    Foo.cpp
dirFoo2
    Foo2.py
    lib\
       bar2.py
```

Foo1 snippet

```
# Foo1.py
import lib.bar1
Class bar1_class:
....
```

Foo2 snippet

```
# Foo2.py
sys.path.append("../dirFoo1/lib")
sys.path.append("../lib") # tried removing this too
import Foo1
....
```

Error message in file Foo2.py:

```
File <path_for_Foo2> 
import Foo1 File <path_for_Foo1> 
from lib.bar1 import bar1_class 
ImportError: No module named bar1
```

When trying to use the library from `dirFoo1\Foo1.py` in `dirFoo2\Foo2.py`. Both `Foo1` and `Foo2` has its own imports from its sub directory lib.

When importing `Foo1` in `Foo2` with the sys path set,

> sys.path.append(dirFoo1)

import error shows up on code in Foo1

> import lib.something_from_bar1

reports error saying  `something_from_bar1` doesnt exist.
seems like its referring to lib in `dirFoo2`.

I do have appropriate `__init__.py` in places under `dirFoo1` and `dirFoo2`.
Is there a way to import the library from another folder that is not linked with `__init__.py` ?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what `Foo2.py` and `Foo1.py` are respectively importing and how. Show us the import statements as you wrote them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of your `dirFooX` folders are on the Python module search path, you will have a conflict between the two `lib` folders, which each define a different `lib` package. Only one of them will be accessible to your code. There are a few different ways you can resolve the conflict.

The simplest would be to rename one or both of the `lib` folders, and update the import statements to match. The name `lib` is not very descriptive for a package that is accessible at the top level of the module namespace. Perhaps they should be `Foo1Lib` and `Foo2Lib`.

Another option is to make `dirFoo1` and `dirFoo2` into packages, so that the `lib` packages are subpackages in two different namespaces. This is probably the best approach, since it shouldn't require any messing around with `sys.path` to make the imports work. Just make sure you run your script from the top level folder (above the `dirFooX` folders, and use the `-m` flag to run  `python -m dirFoo2.Foo2` rather than `python dirFoo2/Foo2.py`. You'll need to update the imports everywhere to use either absolute names (`from dirFoo1.lib.bar1 import bar_class`) or explicit relative names (`from .lib.bar1 import bar_class`).

My final option is probably not really an appropriate choice for your situation, but it would work. Starting in Python 3.3, you can have "namespace" packages, which can load modules from multiple folders rather than just one. If `lib` was a namespace package, it would allow the `bar1.py` and `bar2.py` files to both show up as part of the `lib` package inside the interpreter. This is primarily intended for big projects like `Django` which can have many extra features added on to them by third-party modules. Using namespace packages allows all those add-on modules to be put into a shared namespace. You could make `lib` a namespace package if you *really* want to (though as I said above, `lib` is so generic that it's probably a bad idea to use that name at the top level). All you'd need to do is to delete the `__init__.py` files in each `lib` folder. Like I said though, this is mostly intended for large projects where many modules that should be part of a single package are being written and distributed by separate authors. Unless your two `lib` folders are very closely related, it's probably not an appropriate choice for your situation.

Comment: i ended up renaming the folder under dirFoo2. Thanks for your answer.